# Safe Image with Basic Authorization in Angular5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an image url with basic authorization i need load the images dynamically. After Authorization image will be return as data. How to Handle this image with authorization. Currently I try like this

```
<img [src]=" getImage(res.imageurl) | async" />



  getImage(imageUrl: string): Observable<File> {
   let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(this.domain + '/' + logindata.username + ':' + logindata.password));
    return this.http
        .get(imageUrl,{headers:headers}, { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob })
        .map((res: Response) => res.blob());
}
```

Comment: This worked for me: http://blog.jsgoupil.com/request-image-files-with-angular-2-and-an-bearer-access-token/ (I don't want to put an answer since this is not my work).

Answer (score 3):

Try to use authorisation token instead of username, password.

Like:

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <img [src]="img.src + '?bearer=' + bearToken"/>
    `
})
export class FooComponent {
    img = {
        src: 'https://angular.io/assets/images/logos/angular/logo-nav@2x.png'
    }
    bearerToken  = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9...';
}
```

So images link would be created like this
https://domain/assets/images/xyz.png?bearer=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9…

Comment: I will get Unauthorized

Comment: @Ben10 please check your token.

Comment: For Basic Auth you need to replace 'bearer' with 'basic' e.g. '?basic=' + token

Comment: @MarcUberstein It depends on backend token verification process in your system

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use httpclient to load the image data then to present it in an image tag you need to base64 encode the blob you get back (or base64 it on the server side) then pass it to the src as a [data url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) string like:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{encodedImage}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to return data from response, but u don't subscribe it...

add after `.map(...).subscribe(r => {return r;})`

and remove `return` before `this.http.get`

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement an [interceptor](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8).
In your implementation of intercept() method, you can check the **request** param and see if this is a request to your image.